# Написание условия проверки и вывод в файл

Tags: c#

Есть текстовый файл c содержимым:

```
LM = Logical Machine ID, Rc = Recoveries, Rt = Retries, Cl = Clears

#,LM,Jam ID,Date Occurred,Time Jammed,Rc,Rt,Cl,Jam Text
001,05,015,04/07/15 15:18,00:00:32,01,02,00,Picker can't detect all parts:Ck #1 A1
002,02,030,09/21/15 15:17,00:00:19,00,00,01,ATT unable to detect tray at Gripper
003,01,045,09/21/15 15:15,00:01:32,00,01,00,Aux tray is hanging on guides or stuck in gripper.
004,01,045,09/21/15 15:15,00:00:17,00,01,00,Aux tray is hanging on guides or stuck in gripper.
005,04,030,09/18/15 19:28,00:00:55,01,02,00,Missing sort device(s) on sort boat. B1
006,05,029,09/18/15 19:24,00:01:39,06,06,01,TS Picker missing parts:Ck #1 A1
007,05,016,09/18/15 19:21,00:01:12,00,01,00,Picker detects parts stuck in nests:Ck #1 A1
008,05,016,09/18/15 19:20,00:00:23,00,01,00,Picker detects parts stuck in nests:Ck #1 A1
009,05,016,09/18/15 19:17,00:01:07,02,03,00,Picker detects parts stuck in nests:Ck #1 A1
010,05,016,09/18/15 19:15,00:00:17,00,01,00,Picker detects parts stuck in nests:Ck #1 A1
```

Я его прочитал построчно в массив, при этом разделителем сделал запятую, посчитал среднее время отклонения (пятая колонка) и записал в файл.

Как сделать так, чтобы, если значение пятой колонки больше 2 часов, то он всю строку записывал бы в другой файл?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   //Путь к файлу
            string path = @"C:\Users\a.filatov\Desktop\1\COMMA.txt";

            //Читаем текст в файле построчно
            string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);

            //Объявляем интервал времени
            TimeSpan intervaltimesum = new TimeSpan();

            //Текущее время в ячейке
            TimeSpan current_time;

            //Счётчик
            int countTime = 0;

            //Создание потока для записи в файл
            StreamWriter W = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\a.filatov\Desktop\1\Write.txt");
            StreamWriter A = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\a.filatov\Desktop\1\Writer.txt");

            //Цикл для считывания строк
            for (int i = 19; i < 1000; i++)
            {   
                //Установка разделителем массива запятой
                string[] elements = readText[i].Split(',');

                //Вывод 4 элемента массива в файл
                if (elements.GetLength(0) > 4) W.WriteLine(elements[4]);

                //Сумма времени всех строк
                if (TimeSpan.TryParse(elements[4], out current_time))
                {
                    intervaltimesum += current_time;
                    countTime++;
                }

                //??????????????????????
                var V = Regex.Match(elements[4], @"\d\d:\d\d:\d\d");
                if (!V.Success) continue;
                if (TimeSpan.Parse(V.Value) > new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0))
                {
                    A.WriteLine(V.Value);
                }
            }   
            //Вывод среднего времени в нужном формате
            TimeSpan intervalAverage = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(intervaltimesum.TotalSeconds / countTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Среднее время = {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", intervalAverage);

            //Запись в файл времени   
            W.WriteLine("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}",intervalAverage);
            W.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А через коллекции (Generics) не хотите сделать? Примените потом Linq и выдернете интересующие объекты. Переопределите метод ToString() и в файл

Comment: Нет я сделал по другому

Comment: @Алекс ваш код не падает на данных, приведенных в примере. Запустите код под отладкой - F5 - он остановится при возникновении исключения - и посмотрите номер проблемной строчки и значение `V.Value`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, по быстрому:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("2.txt");

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var a = line.Split(',').Length > 4 ? line.Split(',')[4] : null;
    DateTime date;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(a, out date))
    {
        if (date.Hour >= TimeSpan.FromHours(2).Hours)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("newFile.txt"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Погуглил, можно найти готовый `CVS Helper`, который умеет работать более объектно-ориентировано с данным форматом файлов (ну это если лишняя DLL не помешает Вашему проекту (также думаю в NuGet'e тоже что то есть)).

Comment: Не могу вывести в файл результат проверки

Answer (score 0):

Неизвестно, что в вас там сейчас за код, но скорее всего что-то вроде

```
var dataLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\in.csv")
    .Where(l => !l.StartsWith("#"))
    .ToList();

var data = dataLines.Select(l => l.Split(','))
    .Select(t => new { TimeJammed = TimeSpan.Parse(t[4]) })
    .ToList();

var average = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(data.Average(d => d.TimeJammed.TotalMilliseconds));

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\average.txt", average.ToString());
```

просто сохраняйте оригинальную строку как часть распаршенных данных, и сохраняйте ее в выходной файл:

```
var dataLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\in.csv")
    .Where(l => !l.StartsWith("#"))
    .ToList();

var data = dataLines.Select(l =>
{
    var tokens = l.Split(',');
    return new
    {
        TimeJammed = TimeSpan.Parse(tokens[4]),
        Raw = l
    };
}).ToList();

var average = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(data.Average(d => d.TimeJammed.TotalMilliseconds));

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\average.txt", average.ToString());

var linesToWrite = data.Where(d => d.TimeJammed.TotalHours > 2).Select(l => l.Raw);
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\2.csv", linesToWrite);
```

Comment: Вот мой код, но ругается не получается записать в файл(

Comment: @Алекс воспользуйтесь отладчиком - и проверьте, что вам приходит в `V.Value`